# How to hide / obfuscate code in Pycharm effectively?

Tags: python, security, encryption, pycharm

I want to work on a Windows machine with some privacy / intellectual property related python code within Pycharm.

I want to avoid that somebody else later on can see my code on the local file system (or can recover / undelete it from the SSD based file system). Therefore I am looking for a solution that keeps my python script(s) encrypted on the local file system but editable / usable within Pycharm.

I thought of creating a RAM disk or installing a virtual machine on the Windows computer. Unfortunately, I do not have admin rights on that computer so I cannot install any software nor create virtual machines.

Additionally I can use an USB stick in read only mode on that machine, but cannot write files back to that USB drive.

**I am looking for a solution where I am still able to edit a Python script on that computer within Pycharm, but this file should not be persisted to the file system. Once I have finished my work, the Python script should be written back to the file system in an encrypted way.**

Answer (score 0):

Use an online Idle and save your code online.
If you really want pycharm I would upload the code and delete it from the pc and download again whenever I needed it.

Answer (score 0):

You could work 'in the cloud' where you have an AWS instance that you checkout / clone /develop your work and you just use your computer essentially like a `thin client` for connecting to your remote instance.